# mistake or mistook?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense, antecedents

I saw the following sentence, and am wondering whether "mistake" should be replaced with "mistook."

> Plastic bags have been found in the guts of dead sea turtles, which **mistake** them for jellyfish.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: It is ambiguous. Depending on your interpretation, either could be correct. In fact, the sentence is written in such a way that I hadn't realized at first that it was the sea turtles (dead or not) who had been doing the mistaking. (In other words, I applied *mistake* to the entire first clause—which didn't sound right.) The verb form you use will change the assumption about the referent. If you use *mistake*, it will be assumed you are referring to all sea turtles; if you use *mistook*, it will be assumed you are talking about dead sea turtles.

Comment: Plastic bags have been found in the guts of dead sea turtles which had mistaken them for jellyfish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The present tense is used, among other things, for general statements. Plastic bags *have* been found; this is something that has happened, so it is in the present perfect. Sea turtles *in general* think that carrier bags are jellyfish and try to eat them, so that is in the present tense.

This isn't to say that you couldn't use the past tense, in which case you would be saying the particular turtles that the bags were found in had mistaken them for jellyfish. Just that there is no problem with it being the present tense - to make it a general statement about sea turtles and plastic bags.

Comment: But it is "dead sea turtles" that are in the sentence.

Comment: Late sea turtles, in fact.

Comment: Also have to consider that plastic bags will be found in the guts of sea turtles that are not dead yet, but have swallowed plastic bags...

Comment: I believe any native reader would understand that, in the general statement "which mistake them for jellyfish", the antecedent of *which* is "sea turtles", not "dead sea turtles". This happens, that the antecedent of a relative pronoun is intended to be an earlier noun *without* any adjectives. All sea turtles make the mistake, not just the dead ones. And even living ones may have bags in their guts.

Comment: If so, shouldn't "dead" be removed from the original sentence?

Comment: No, because they only *have* found them in dead turtles. They are there *to be found* in other turtles, we can confidently assume. However, by the time anyone finds them, those turtles will be dead as well.

Comment: If we analyze the sentence grammatically, the antecedent to "which" is "dead sea turtles."
Do dead sea turtles mistake plastic bags for jellyfish? Or is that what living sea turtles do?

Comment: I can't speak authoritatively on what any particular formal grammar rules demand. I can tell you that, in actual practice, sometimes the antecedent is a noun shorn of its adjectives. That's what I read as having happened here.

Comment: It should be mistook in the sentence as we are talking of dead sea turtle.  To make it a general statemen, we need to change the sentence.  ..................., which implies sea turtles mistake them for jellyfish.

Comment: Folks, all I can tell your is that this is normal, natural language in my experience as a native speaker. It would be an extremely rare school teacher here who would take any issue with it whatsoever. And they would probably have theire colleagues tell them they were in the wrong.

Comment: (blasted gesture typing... pretty embarassing to end up with errors like that on *this* SE...)